# CATransform3D breaks layer order?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Basically I want to build the scrollView like the one in iOS7 safari tab switcher. I use CATransform3D to get the feeling of oblique. However when I employ transform the layers just don't display in proper order.(They are in correct order before transform, seems like a total reversal in order.Back layer jumps to the front). How can I fix this thorny problem?
By the way in my case superView.bringSubViewToFront doesn't work.

My code:

```
     //Create imageView
    ...
    scroller.addSubview(imageView)
    let layer = imageView.layer
     //Set shadow
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    layer.shadowRadius = 2
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(6, -10)

      //Transform, if without following code the layer order is correct
    var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    transform.m34 = 0.0009
    let radiants = 0.11*M_PI
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(radiants), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    scroller.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)//It doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found that if you set the z axis to 1.0 in CATransform3DTranslate the layer become in front of other layers, so just make it 0.